# Join two tables/add columns to original with common key in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is pretty simple but googling  it brings up how to do this with NO common key. I have one column full of common keys (in this case provider_num)

Basically my first table (called 's10') looks like this:

```
provider_num | provider_name | state | phone_number`

10001        | johns creek   | ga    | 555-5555`
```

and the second is like this (called 'hs')

```
provider_num | latitude | longitude | IDS_num

10001        | -89.0023 | -82.4729  | stn0021
```

I'd like to end up wiith a table that looks something like this

```
provider_num | provider_name | state | phone_number | latitude | longitude | IDS_num
```

Is this possible?

So far I have just written a simple insert like this

```
INSERT INTO s10
hs.latitude, hs.longitude, hs.IDS_num
where s10.provider_num = hs.provider_num
```

But I'd like to know if I am missing something, such a pre-defining columns in s10, etc. before I run it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes check `inner join`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the table `s10` already exists, but only with the limited set of columns? You then want to add the columns from `hs` to the `s10` table for a single in the database, or do you want to produce that output at query time?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I'm trying to add the specified columns from hs into s10. s10 already exists but with the limited columns, you are correct. Ideally I want one table that has fields from both.

Comment: are you looking for a query to get the data from both tables?  Or are you seeking to eliminate the second table and have everything on the first table?

Comment: @nomistic I don't want to eliminate hs and I don't need "output" anywhere persay, but I DO wan't the columns I specified in hs to be "copied" over to the s10 table and the data to match on the row based on the provider_num common field.

Comment: for retrieving data from db you can simply use join but for inserting data in db you can not use what you have in mind. you either have to create a new table with all the desired fields which is the combination of both tables or if you want to use your current structure, you can create a procedure and send your parameters to it and the procedure inserts related values to each table.

Comment: @Habitat "_I DO wan't the columns I specified in hs to be "copied" over to the s10 table_" ... If the `hs` table remains, do you expect inserts/updates to _either_ table to be reflected in _both_ tables? That could be done with triggers, but I  would really advise against it. You would be permanently duplicating data and creating a complex and potentially fragile situation.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski neither table is updated EVER. It's simply two sets of data that I have which happened to come in two different files and all I want is to combine them in the right place

Comment: @Habitat Okay then - my first solution below should be fine then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot both create the columns in `s10` and populate their values in the same SQL statement. You would first need an `ALTER TABLE` to add the columns, followed by an `UPDATE` (using an `INNER JOIN`) to populate them:

```
-- s10 already exists, but with limited columns
-- Add the other columns (use the correct data types - I just guessed here)
ALTER TABLE s10
  ADD latitude DECIMAL(10,2) [NULL or other attrs],
  ADD longitude DECIMAL(10,2) [NULL or other attrs],
  ADD IDS_num VARCHAR(32);
```

After adding the relevant columns, execute an `UPDATE` with a join ([using the "multi-table" syntax described in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)):

```
UPDATE s10 INNER JOIN hs ON s10.provider_num = hs.provider_num
  SET 
    s10.latitude = hs.latitude,
    s10.longitude = hs.longitude,
    s10.IDS_num = hs.IDS_num;
```

An alternative solution would be to just leave the two tables in place as they are and create a view which queries them both:

```
CREATE VIEW combined_tables AS (
  SELECT
    s10.provider_num,
    provider_name,
    state,
    phone_number,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    IDS_num
  FROM 
   s10 
   INNER JOIN hs ON s10.provider_num = hs.provider_num
);
```

But if `hs` merely contains additional attributes to the entities identified by `provider_num`, it does make sense to eliminate the `hs` table by combining both into `s10`.

Yet another alternative is to use `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` to create a new table by querying the others (with the same `SELECT` used in the view):

```
CREATE TABLE s10_combined AS 
 SELECT
    s10.provider_num,
    provider_name,
    state,
    phone_number,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    IDS_num
  FROM 
   s10 
   INNER JOIN hs ON s10.provider_num = hs.provider_num;
```

The above produces a new table `s10_combined`, after which you may drop the other two.  Given all these alternatives though, I would just stick with the first and perform an `ALTER` followed by `UPDATE`.

Comment: `[NULL or other attrs]` Sorry but what does this mean? Is it the initial value in the table for that column?

Comment: @Habitat I just meant to include any other attributes on those column definitions necessary - like `NULL, DEFAULT` etc. Since I don't know the exact original definition of the `hs` table.

Comment: :Edit I removed [null] from the end and it added null automatically, which was what I initially needed anyway. I marked your answer as correct. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT` statement. In your case:

```
CREATE TABLE newtablename AS
SELECT the-fields-you-want FROM s10 INNER JOIN hs ON s10.provider_num = hs.provider_num
```

then you can drop the original two tables and rename  the newly created one the way you like. And do not forget to create the necessary indexes on the new table.